# not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get

Tags: go

I was working in Google CLoud and all was fine.. but when I clone all my project in my PC, I have this messages in every JSON struct.

**struct field tag `bson:"edad" json:"edad, omitempty"` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: suspicious space in struct tag valuestructtag**

This is my Struct

```
type Usuario struct {
    ID        bson.RawValue `bson:"_id" json:"id, omitempty"`
    Nombre    string        `bson:"nombre" json:"nombre, omitempty"`
    Apellidos string        `bson:"apellidos" json:"apellidos, omitempty"`
    Edad      int           `bson:"edad" json:"edad, omitempty"`
    Email     string        `bson:"email" json:"email"`
    Password  string        `bson:"password" json:"password, omitempty"`
}
```

What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the spaces between the `,` and `omitempty`.

Answer (score 48):

Remove the space after the comma before `omitempty`, then the error message will go away.

`bson:"password" json:"password,omitempty"` *(should be like this)*

In addition, this is a warning not an error. You should still be able to run your project.

Comment: The space after the comma before omitempty is not missing, it should be removed. The wording of the answer is misleading, but the answer is correct :)