# Struct field tag `name` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag pair

Tags: go, struct, reflection, compiler-warnings

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59959839/2441637), but it is different than my case, I've the below code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `name`
    Age  int64  `age`
}

func main() {
    var u User = User{"bob", 10}

    res, err := JSONEncode(u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))

}

func JSONEncode(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    refObjVal := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    refObjTyp := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    if refObjVal.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return buf.Bytes(), fmt.Errorf(
            "val of kind %s is not supported",
            refObjVal.Kind(),
        )
    }
    buf.WriteString("{")
    pairs := []string{}
    for i := 0; i < refObjVal.NumField(); i++ {
        structFieldRefObj := refObjVal.Field(i)
        structFieldRefObjTyp := refObjTyp.Field(i)

        switch structFieldRefObj.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            strVal := structFieldRefObj.Interface().(string)
            pairs = append(pairs, `"`+string(structFieldRefObjTyp.Tag)+`":"`+strVal+`"`)
        case reflect.Int64:
            intVal := structFieldRefObj.Interface().(int64)
            pairs = append(pairs, `"`+string(structFieldRefObjTyp.Tag)+`":`+strconv.FormatInt(intVal, 10))
        default:
            return buf.Bytes(), fmt.Errorf(
                "struct field with name %s and kind %s is not supprted",
                structFieldRefObjTyp.Name,
                structFieldRefObj.Kind(),
            )
        }
    }

    buf.WriteString(strings.Join(pairs, ","))
    buf.WriteString("}")

    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

It works perfectly, and give output as:

```bash
{"name":"bob","age":10}
```

But as VS code, it gives me the below problems:

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, if you post your comments as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that that's just a warning telling you that you're not following convention. The code, as you already know, compiles and runs and outputs the result you want: https://go.dev/play/p/gxcv8qPVZ6z.

To avoid the warning, disable your linter, or, better yet, follow the convention by using `key:"value"` in the struct tags and then extract the value by using the [`Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.18.3#StructTag.Get) method: https://go.dev/play/p/u0VTGL48TjO.

---

https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.18.3#StructTag

> A StructTag is the tag string in a struct field.
>
> **By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally
> space-separated key:"value" pairs.** Each key is a non-empty string
> consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '),
> quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using
> U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

Comment: Thangs a lot, this explains the confusion I got, and provides the proper way to do it, and get the required resultsd.

Answer (score 5):

Struct tag supposed to be a `key:"value"`, `field:"name"` for example.

```
type User struct {
    Name string `field:"name"`
    Age  int64  `field:"age"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this cause wrong output with my code above, with this, I'm getting `{"field:"name"":"bob","field:"age"":10}` instead of `{"name":"bob","age":10}`

Comment: That's how your code works, `structFieldRefObjTyp.Tag` if you want a value you  should parse tag and extract value.

Answer (score 5):

instead of field as in another answer you can use `json:"keyname"`

```golang
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int64  `json:"age"`
}
```